# PHP.Is it possible to use a variable in file_put_contents?

Tags: php, variables, file-put-contents

I want to create a text file with the name  **abc.txt**
.So I try this

```
$word="abc";

$file='"'.$word.".txt".'"'    //for having "abc.txt"

file_put_contents($file,'content content...');
```

And I have this error:   **Warning: file_put_contents("abc.txt"): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:....**

Why this is not working?
I mustn't use       file_put_contents(abc.txt,'content content...'); 
Thanks

Comment: Just `$file = "$word.txt";` or `$file = $word.".txt";`

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Thank you very much @AbraCadaver.This works   $file = $word.".txt";

Answer (score -1):

```
$word = "abc";

$file = $word . '.txt';    //for having "abc.txt"

file_put_contents($file,'content content...');
```

"abc" is already in the variable and then you add '.txt';